# Gaining input below a UITabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I've got a banner that I need to display below a tab bar within a tab bar controller.  Getting it to display isn't the hard part, I have that solved already, however it seems somehow that the method I am using seems to be putting it outside the normal area for input to be received.

Basically, I am using this banner as an advertisement, but I do not wish for it to cover the tab bar.

Here's the code I am using to create the banner below the tab bar:

```
    const float footerHeight = 34.5;
    const float statusBarHeight = 20.f;
    const float viewHeight = 480 - statusBarHeight - bannerHeight - footerHeight;
    const float viewY = 0 + statusBarHeight + bannerHeight;

    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, viewHeight, 320, footerHeight)];
    [footerView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [footerView addSubview:footerButton];

    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:footerView];
    [footerView release];

    self.tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, viewY, 320, viewHeight);
```

just for reference in some of the variables there is also a header above the top of the view as well.  `footerButton` is a UIButton that I have created and hooked up in IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately managed to work around this issue by putting a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the root `UIWindow` object and then manually doing the rect cheecks to see if it is within the normal, smaller bounds of the tabBarController and forwarded the input to my footer bar otherwise

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.window];
    if ( touchPoint.y > 57 && touchPoint.y < 446 )
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

-(IBAction) handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    if ( sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded )
    {
        //handle
        CGPoint tapPoint = [sender locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.window];
        if ( tapPoint.y >= 446 )
        {
            [footerButton clickedAd];
        }
        NSLog(@"(%f,%f)", tapPoint.x, tapPoint.y );
    }
}
```